# Ettercap - ARP poisoning unsuccessful

Tags: arp, sniffing

Yesterday I successfully performed a MITM attack by ARP poisoning between my router and my Windows7 computer. I used Ettercap on a Linux machine.

However, today, running the same command does not work anymore. It looks like Ettercap cannot reach my computer, which IP is 192.168.0.17.

Here is what I got :

[image]

We can see that the only host added to the list is the router one (192.168.0.1)... What I don't understand is that it was working few hours ago.

I noticed also another thing.

using the command

```
sudo arpspoof -i wlp20s0 -t 192.168.0.17 192.168.0.1
```

The ARP poisonning DOES work this time. But now the problem is that it is acting like a DDOS on my victim... It completely loses internet connection.
And before it was not, it was working as expected.

So I guess something has changed on my victim computer but I cannot figure what.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> IP forwarding is the ability for an operating system to accept incoming network packets on one interface, recognize that it is not meant for the system itself, but that it should be passed on to another network, and then forwards it accordingly.

From https://openvpn.net/faq/what-is-and-how-do-i-enable-ip-forwarding-on-linux/
When you perform MITM packets that don't match your IP are being sent to you and are not passed on correctly so the victim can reach out to the internet. With IP forwarding enabled your computer will reroute the packets correctly and the attacked computer will have access to the internet.
On Linux if I remember correctly:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

will fo the job.

Answer (score -1):

Arp replies are stored in cache, so first of all do some tricks here:

Remove arp cache from windpws with **cmd**. 
(Cause the first priority is the cache and if host cant find the mac address it will generate an ARP request,then your router will repliy with ARP reply)

**issue this command to see arp table:**
*arp -a*

When you do Mitm with arp spoof and your computer looses internet connectivity it might be your DNS misconfiguration.
You ll need to enable dns server.
(If wan to brows web pages)

Try to do it with ettercap and enable arp poision and dns spoof module.